# when I'm working on a same branch with co-worker

Tags: git

when I'm working on a same branch with co-worker
and while I'm working on, she pushed new codes.
In this case which one should I do?

1. git add . => git commit => git push => git pull
2. git pull => git add . => git commit => git push (or push later)

Comment: Create separate branches — it saves angst.  They're lightweight.  You can synchronize them when necessary — and merge back into the main branch when your changes are ready.

Comment: Neither of those options make much sense. You want to commit your local changes, then pull in hers, then push back (assuming your commit is ready to be pushed). Try `git pull --rebase` to have some level of automatic reconciliation of unrelated changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The first option will not work because the push will be rejected because the branch has changed.
2. The second option is not ideal because it get be complicated if both of you changed the same code.
3. The 3rd option, using your notation, will be to 'add . => commit => pull => push' and may require rebasing, and would arguably be the usual way, *if you must work on a single branch*.

**Having said that, it's best to work on separate branches.**

With separate branches you can:

1. Use a better review process (via pull requests) *and*
2. push your changes at any time (e.g. at 16:59) with no risk that the changes will be rejected.
3. push your changes even if they are not finished (e.g. don't compile) without impacting other workers.